# How to run function asynchronously as soon as one of any stream is updated in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am currently gathering information about financial market prices using a websocket API and I want to do the following:

- Monitor stream 1 and stream 2 asynchronously
- As soon as data is updated on any of the streams, run a function

My current code looks like this with asyncio:

```
async def watch_data(stream):
    """Get a ticker and print ask and bid"""
    stock = await stream.watch_prices(stock)
    return stock


async do_something(stock1, stock2):
    print(f"Stock 1: {stock1} - Stock 2: {stock2}")


async def main(loop):

    while True:
        stock1 = await watch_data(stream1)
        stock2 = await watch_data(stream2)
        await do_something(stock1, stock2)
```

Currently I am getting the print from 'do_something' when stream1 updates, then waits for stream2 to update, then print both. I would like to get the print as soon as any of the streams send an update through the 'watch_prices' function.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care that one of the streams if updated you should look at [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait).

```
async def main():
    while True:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait([stream1, stream2], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        await do_something(done.result())
```

If you want to operate on each of them as they're done, check out [`asyncio.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed).

```
async def main():
    while True:
        for f in asyncio.as_completed([stream1, stream2]):
            await do_something(f.result())
```

Both of these, however, have the problem that at some point you'll still be waiting for all of the streams to update before restarting any of the others. If that's what you're going for, you'll probably want to run a coroutine for each stream and use something like [`asyncio.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue) to communicate the results back to the coroutine that passes the results to `do_something`.

Comment: As defined by the OP, `do_something` expects the value, and your code passes it a future. This can be fixed by changing the first example to invoke `do_something` with `await do_something([f.result() for f in done])`.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks

Comment: I believe the modified code still has issues. In the first snippet, `done` is a collection, so you cannot just call `result()` on it, you need to use a list comprehension or equivalent (as in my previous comment). Also, `asyncio.as_completed` doesn't return futures that are done, it (somewhat confusingly) returns coroutine objects that you have to *await* to get the actual result. So in the second example you'd have `await do_something(await f)`.

Comment: This is what I get for doing all of this on a phone. I'll fix it up with working code a little later.